Error while creating React Native app using Expo
I am new to React-Native, So I have started learning from the Native Documentation.
So I have installed the NodeJS, in my machine.
After installed the NodeJS, I am following the below documentation for developing the React Native app.
https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/
I have opened the Command prompt and run the below command

npx create-expo-app@latest

Getting the below 2 errors

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js'
Error:
Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'

The below screenshot having the full error message

Can you please suggest, what is the issue here
Thanks In Advance

Can you check your node version by using node -v?

@Thomasino73 v20.18.0

Try doing the following - npm install -g

Getting the below issue
ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\user'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

It seems that npm has broken when installing. Try removing C:\Users\user\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm and npm-cache folders and reinstall Node.

Thomasino73, After reinstall and install again, getting the same issue
no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\user'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
